# Stylecop doesn't understand <inheritdoc />

Tags: c#, documentation, stylecop, inheritdoc

I'm trying to use Stylecop 4.7.31
I have a project, where an interface is declared:

```
public interface IRmlManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the notification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notificationData">The notification data.</param>
    void AddNotification(RmlNotificationData notificationData);
}
```

and another project, where an implementation of the interface:

```
public class RmlManager : IRmlManager
{
........
    /// ???
    void AddNotification(RmlNotificationData notificationData);
........
}
```

if I use `<inheritdoc />` instead of ???, Stylecop ignores it and produces errors:

```
BusinessLogic\RmlManager.cs(39,1): error : SA1604: The documentation header must have a summary tag.
BusinessLogic\RmlManager.cs(39,1): error : SA1611: The documentation header must contain param tags matching the element's parameter list.
```

have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
According to google, Stylecop supports this tag starting approximately from 4.1 version

Comment: In your snippet, `RmlManager` does not appear to implement `IRmlManager`. Is that just a typo? If not, then I assume that's the issue.

Comment: yes, it's a typo, fixed.  thank you for the notice

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell you, but Inheritdoc IS supported by StyleCop, as per http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/6637.

So, this can only be assumed to be a - well - specific instance (i.e. it does undrestand inheritdoc, just this particular example is a bug behavior).

Given that inheritdoc is generally accepted, I Would suggest you ask on a stylecop specific list (open a discussion on their site on codeplax at http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions) and possibly make a repro case and open a bug.

Comment: thank you for the link, but I've already seen it. My main question is: maybe I did something wrong, or Stylecop doesn't see documentation from interfaces, if they are in different projects, or maybe something else... I just wonder, maybe someone had similar problem and cab share their experience.